# Spring batch : Assemble a job rather than configuring it (Extensible job configuration)

Tags: spring, file, annotations, spring-batch

**Background**

I am working on designing a file reading layer that can read delimited files and load it in a `List`. I have decided to use Spring Batch because it provides a lot of scalability options which I can leverage for different sets of files depending on their size.

**The requirement**

1. I want to design a generic Job API that can be used to read any delimited file.
2. There should be a single Job structure that should be used for parsing every delimited file. For example, if the system needs to read 5 files, there will be 5 jobs (one for each file). The only way the 5 jobs will be different from each other is that they will use a different `FieldSetMapper`, column name, directory path and additional scaling parameters such as `commit-interval` and `throttle-limit`.
3. The user of this API should not need to configure a Spring
   batch job, step, chunking, partitioning, etc on his own when a new file type is introduced in the system.
4. All that the user needs to do is to provide the `FieldsetMapper`to be used by the job along with the `commit-interval`, `throttle-limit` and the directory where each type of file will be placed.
5. There will be one predefined directory per file. Each directory can contain multiple files of the same type and format. A `MultiResourcePartioner` will be used to look inside a directory. The number of partitions = number of files in the directory.

My requirement is to build a Spring Batch infrastructure that gives me a unique job I can launch once I have the bits and pieces that will make up the job.

**My solution :**

I created an abstract configuration class that will be extended by concrete configuration classes (There will be 1 concrete class per file to be read).

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public abstract class AbstractFileLoader<T> {

    private static final String FILE_PATTERN = "*.dat";

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver;

    public final Job createJob(Step s1, JobExecutionListener listener) {
        return jobs.get(this.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener)
                .start(s1).build();
    }

    public abstract Job loaderJob(Step s1, JobExecutionListener listener);

    public abstract FieldSetMapper<T> getFieldSetMapper();

    public abstract String getFilesPath();

    public abstract String[] getColumnNames();

    public abstract int getChunkSize();

    public abstract int getThrottleLimit();

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}")
    public FlatFileItemReader<T> reader(String file) {
        FlatFileItemReader<T> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<T>();
        String path = file.substring(file.indexOf(":") + 1, file.length());
        FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(path);
        reader.setResource(resource);
        DefaultLineMapper<T> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<T>();
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(getFieldSetMapper());
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(",");
        tokenizer.setNames(getColumnNames());
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
        reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<T, T> processor() {
        // TODO add transformations here
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public ListItemWriter<T> writer() {
        ListItemWriter<T> writer = new ListItemWriter<T>();
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step readStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
            ItemReader<T> reader, ItemWriter<T> writer,
            ItemProcessor<T, T> processor, TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {

        final Step readerStep = stepBuilderFactory
                .get(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " ReadStep:slave")
                .<T, T> chunk(getChunkSize()).reader(reader)
                .processor(processor).writer(writer).taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
                .throttleLimit(getThrottleLimit()).build();

        final Step partitionedStep = stepBuilderFactory
                .get(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " ReadStep:master")
                .partitioner(readerStep)
                .partitioner(
                        this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " ReadStep:slave",
                        partitioner()).taskExecutor(taskExecutor).build();

        return partitionedStep;

    }

    /*
     * @Bean public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() { return new
     * SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(); }
     */

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Partitioner partitioner() {
        MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
        Resource[] resources;
        try {
            resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("file:"
                    + getFilesPath() + FILE_PATTERN);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "I/O problems when resolving the input file pattern.", e);
        }
        partitioner.setResources(resources);
        return partitioner;
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public JobExecutionListener listener(ListItemWriter<T> writer) {
        return new JobCompletionNotificationListener<T>(writer);
    }

    /*
     * Use this if you want the writer to have job scope (JIRA BATCH-2269). Also
     * change the return type of writer to ListItemWriter for this to work.
     */
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor() {
            @Override
            protected void doExecute(final Runnable task) {
                // gets the jobExecution of the configuration thread
                final JobExecution jobExecution = JobSynchronizationManager
                        .getContext().getJobExecution();
                super.doExecute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        JobSynchronizationManager.register(jobExecution);

                        try {
                            task.run();
                        } finally {
                            JobSynchronizationManager.close();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Let's say I have to read Invoice data for the sake of discussion. I can therefore extend the above class for creating an `InvoiceLoader` :

```
@Configuration
public class InvoiceLoader extends AbstractFileLoader<Invoice>{

    private class InvoiceFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Invoice> {

        public Invoice mapFieldSet(FieldSet f) {
            Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
            invoice.setNo(f.readString("INVOICE_NO");
            return e;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public FieldSetMapper<Invoice> getFieldSetMapper() {
        return new InvoiceFieldSetMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public String getFilesPath() {
        return "I:/CK/invoices/partitions/";
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getColumnNames() {
        return new String[] { "INVOICE_NO", "DATE"};
    }


    @Override
    @Bean(name="invoiceJob")
    public Job loaderJob(Step s1,
            JobExecutionListener listener) {
        return createJob(s1, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getChunkSize() {
        return 25254;
    }

    @Override
    public int getThrottleLimit() {
        return 8;
    }

}
```

Let's say I have one more class called `Inventory` that extends `AbstractFileLoader.`

On application startup, I can load these two annotation configurations as follows :

```
AbstractApplicationContext context1 = new   AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(InvoiceLoader.class, InventoryLoader.class);
```

Somewhere else in my application two different threads can launch the jobs as follows :

Thread 1 :

```
    JobLauncher jobLauncher1 = context1.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    Job job1 = context1.getBean("invoiceJob", Job.class);
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher1.run(job1, jobParams1);
```

Thread 2 :

```
    JobLauncher jobLauncher1 = context1.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    Job job1 = context1.getBean("inventoryJob", Job.class);
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher1.run(job1, jobParams1);
```

The advantage of this approach is that everytime there is a new file to be read, all that the developer/user has to do is subclass `AbstractFileLoader` and implement the required abstract methods without the need to get into the details of how to assemble the job.

**The questions :**

1. I am new to Spring batch so I may have overlooked some of the not-so-obvious issues with this approach such as shared internal objects in Spring batch that may cause two jobs running together to fail or obvious issues such as scoping of the beans.
2. Is there a better way to achieve my objective?
3. The `fileName` attribute of the `@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}")` is always being assigned the value as `I:/CK/invoices/partitions/` which is the value returned by `getPath`method in `InvoiceLoader` even though the getPath`method in`InventoryLoader`returns a different value.

Comment: Where's the question here?

Comment: Sorry if I was being unclear. The question is in the last two paragraphs. I want to assemble a new `Job` on the go rather than having a pre-configured job that I launch The developer will provide a subclass of the `FieldSetMapper` and an `ItemWriter` along with additional parameters such as commit-interval to my `FileLoader`. The `FileLoader` should then assemble these components into a `Job` and launch the `Job`. I want to assemble jobs on behalf of the developer rather than asking them to configure them. Point 1 and 2 in my post specify the requirement. Editing my post to make it a clear!

Comment: So you want the "user" to provide the beans for `FieldSetMapper`, `ItemWriter` and so on?

Comment: @Artefacto That's right. I want the user to provide only the `FieldSetMapper` and the `ItemWriter` along with additional parameters mentioned in my post. I will take these components and assemble a `Job` and launch it. So there are no pre-configured jobs here. I have to assemble one out of the provided components and then launch it. Also, this method may be called many times within the lifetime of the application so each job has to be unique but I should be able to reuse components such as the `JobLauncher`. I frankly don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: @Artefacto The reason for assembling the jobs rather than asking the "users" to configure them is that the "users" are mostly support guys who know their way around a little bit of Java code to be able to write simple Java classes like the `FieldSetMapper` implementation. Asking them to configure `Spring batch` jobs is out of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is passing them as job parameters. For instance:

```
@Bean
Job job() {
    jobs.get("myJob").start(step1(null)).build()
}

@Bean
@JobScope
Step step1(@Value('#{jobParameters["commitInterval"]}') commitInterval) {
    steps.get('step1')
            .chunk((int) commitInterval)
            .reader(new IterableItemReader(iterable: [1, 2, 3, 4], name: 'foo'))
            .writer(writer(null))
            .build()
}

@Bean
@JobScope
ItemWriter writer(@Value('#{jobParameters["writerClass"]}') writerClass) {
    applicationContext.classLoader.loadClass(writerClass).newInstance()
}
```

With `MyWriter`:

```
class MyWriter implements ItemWriter<Integer> {

    @Override
    void write(List<? extends Integer> items) throws Exception {
        println "Write $items"
    }
}
```

Then executed with:

```
def jobExecution = launcher.run(ctx.getBean(Job), new JobParameters([
        commitInterval: new JobParameter(3),
        writerClass: new JobParameter('MyWriter'), ]))
```

Output is:

```
INFO: Executing step: [step1]
Write [1, 2, 3]
Write [4]
Feb 24, 2016 2:30:22 PM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1 run
INFO: Job: [SimpleJob: [name=myJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{commitInterval=3, writerClass=MyWriter}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
Status is: COMPLETED, job execution id 0
  #1 step1 COMPLETED
```

Full example [here](https://gist.github.com/131635de24e21b1f905e).

Comment: This makes sense. But there's still the problem of reusing this code for creating multiple jobs. If I want to launch 5 jobs that have the same configuration, how would I do that without having to touch your configuration classes.

Comment: @CKing You mean 5 job instances or five different jobs? In this scenario, there is only one job. If you want several similar jobs, you can share configuration through `@Import`.

Comment: Makes sense. I will have to load each of these job configuration classes in their own Spring container through AnnotationConfigApplicationContext right

Comment: I have edited the question with an alternate approach. Your answer gave me a few ideas on how to move forward with this. My question may make my objective a bit more clear now.

Comment: After playing around with a lot of options, yours seems to be the only one that works when it comes to annotation. Thanks :)