# How can I achieve a level of abstraction on different job configuration?

Tags: spring-batch

Having the same issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35597456/spring-batch-assemble-a-job-rather-than-configuring-it-extensible-job-configu) on my application. Working fine with one Batch Job but if I tried to add another required classes and implement abstract methods to expose them for assembling in the parent `AbstractFileLoader`, the application complains of cannot autowire a bean of type `FieldSetMapper<ConcreteImpl>` which is exactly the same as the working one and I don't know why?! although the defined class has `@Component` Annotation.

FieldSetMapper:-

```
@Component("accountFieldSetMapper")
public class AccountFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Account>{

    @Override
    public Account mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        Account account= new Account();
        account.setId(fieldSet.readString("id"));
        account.setBalance(fieldSet.readDouble("balance"));
        return account;
    }

}
```

Configuration:-

```
@Configuration
public class AccountConfig extends GeneralConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("accountFieldSetMapper")
    private FieldSetMapper<Account> accountFieldSetMapper;

}
```

Stack trace:-

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field accountFieldSetMapper in com.app.AccountConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=accountFieldSetMapper)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper' in your configuration.
```

**Update: Job Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public abstract class GeneralConfig implements BatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    DataSource datasource;

    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    @Bean
    public Step batchStep(String stepName) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(stepName)
                .<~>chunk(10)
                .faultTolerant()                                               
                .skipLimit(100)
                .reader(reader(null))
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer(null))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job batchJob(String jobName) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(jobName).start(batchStep(jobName)).build();
    }

}
```

For Launching the Job I use the Job Name and get the bean and job launcher to launch it.

```
Job currentJob = appContext.getBean(jobName, Job.class);
jobLauncher.run(currentJob , jobParams);
```

Application Context:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);

    }
```

Comment: please share the stack trace and source code.

Comment: I think spring can't setup context for your second batch job. Can you show how do you configure it?

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko It has the same configuration as the first they all are configured in the parent ```GeneralConfig``` and everyone provides it's abstract methods so if there is a problem in the parent the first would have not worked !

Comment: I've meant how do you configure first and second job. It should be started either via '@SpringBootApplication' configuration or manually. Anyways it has nothing to do with spring batch but with Spring/SpringBoot

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko I have updated the question. Now I get a different error because I have abstract ```GeneralConfig``` that extends ```BatchConfigurer``` all the children extends ```GeneralConfig```.

Comment: And what is that different error? :) Anyways I guess you can split your configuration for every job with different profiles https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko The new error is spring doesn't accept to have many descendent classes for ```BatchConfigurer```, because all the children extend from ```GeneralConfig``` which in turn extends ```BatchConfigurer``` I end up having many children for```BatchConfigurer```. I don't think its a good Idea to split them according to profiles I'm thinking to make them different micro-service.